# Can a local ring have more than one prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, localization

A local ring is defined as a ring which has a unique maximal ideal. This unique maximal ideal consists of only non-units and contains **all** the non-units of the ring $R$. So examples of local rings include any field, or rings localised at prime ideals and so on.

My question is: can we have a local ring which has more than one prime ideal? I can't seem to think of any examples where this is the case.

(In response  to the comments below, I have realised that when $R$ is a domain, then $(0)$ is also a prime ideal, but are there any examples where $R$ isn't a domain?)

Comment: What about $\{0\}$?

Comment: I would have thought 'most' examples one get to know have more than one prime ideal. For instance any commutative local integral domain which is not a field.

Comment: ${0}$ is a prime ideal if and only if $R$ is a domain isn't it, i was looking for examples where $R$ isn't necessarily a domain; maybe i should edit it in the question

Comment: Polynomial ring would be one of a good example. Let $R$ be any commutative ring which is not a field, Then $R[x]$ has prime ideal $(x)$ which is not maximal. Maybe look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension if you want to know more about this.

Comment: oh, is $R[x]$ a local ring? I am not really sure if it is? Because if we take the set of all non-units in R[x] , then surely they don't form an ideal

Comment: Ah indeed.. If you localise it it works though (do you know about localisation?)

Comment: Yes I am aware of localisation, so you are saying, if I localise $R[x]$ at $(x)$ then the resultant ring is obviously a local ring, and that $(x)$ is a prime ideal of the local ring?

Comment: That would be true but it would also be a maximum ideal. However if you localise at the maximal ideal of $R[x]$ containing $x$ (this exists and is strictly bigger than $x$) then it works.

Comment: ok, i will have a think about this, i am just getting started on localisation so might take me some time! Thanks for  the help though

Comment: You need a local ring which is not a pid.  See [dvr](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring)

Comment: I would turn the question backwards and ask *you*: can you give examples of local rings with just one prime ideal?

Comment: It can have infinitely many, think to $\Bbb Q[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ and $(x+ay)$ for any $a \in \Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 16):

This question is intimately tied to the idea of *dimension*.  Given a commutative ring $R$, its [(Krull) dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) is defined as the supremum of the lengths of chains of all prime ideals.

The name dimension for this quantity makes sense because the coordinate ring of an $n$-dimensional affine variety has Krull dimension $n$.  Localization has a geometric interpretation, too: a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ corresponds to an irreducible variety $V$.  The localization $R_\mathfrak{p}$ consists of all rational functions that are defined at all points of $V$.

If $R$ is a local ring and its unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is the *only* prime ideal, then $R$ has dimension $0$, which, if $R$ is Noetherian, is equivalent to being [Artinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring).

The geometric interpretation above indicates how to produce a local ring with any number of prime ideals.  Given a positive integer $n$, consider $n$-dimensional affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ over a field $k$ of characteristic zero.  Its coordinate ring is $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, and if we localize at the prime (maximal, actually) ideal $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, we obtain the local ring $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]_{(x_1, \ldots, x_n)}$ which consists of all rational functions on $\mathbb{A}^n$ that are defined at the origin.  By the [correspondence theorem for prime ideals in a localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring#Properties), this ring has a chain of prime ideals
$$
(0) \subsetneq (x_1) \subsetneq (x_1, x_2) \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)
$$
of length $n$.

As for an example where $R$ is not a domain:  an affine variety is irreducible iff its coordinate ring is a domain, so we need to consider reducible varieties.  Let $A = \frac{k[x,y]}{(xy)}$ which is the coordinate ring of the union of the lines $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ in the plane.  Let $\mathfrak{m} = (x,y)$ and let
$$
R = A_\mathfrak{m} = \left(\frac{k[x,y]}{(xy)}\right)_{(x,y)}
$$
which is the local ring at the origin.  Then $(x), (y)$, and $(x,y)$ are all prime ideals of $R$.

Answer (score 10):

For an explicit example, consider $k[[x,y]]$, formal power series over a field $k$, in two indeterminates. The unique maximal ideal is the set of series with no constant term; among the nonzero prime ideals are $(x)$ and $(y)$.